# HA Tomcat Clustering: starting node after crash

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, cluster-computing, reverse-proxy

i want to run a tomcat (v7) cluster behind a nginx reverse proxy. 
in my testenviroment i've setup the tomcat cluster (2 nodes [A/B]) with session replication and the nginx as a reverse proxy (round robin).

when both nodes (A and B) are running the nginx will relay the requests via round robin.

- 1st request => node A
- 2nd request => node B
- 3rd request => node A ...

everything works fine, even when i stop a tomcat node (node B).

- 1st request => node A
- 2nd request => node A
- 3rd request => node A ...

now the problem: when i start a node B (e.g. after rebooting the machine) the nginx is trying to relay every 2nd request to the node B, but it need some minutes to start (the nodes are carring ~300 applications so it need ~20min to start) while the tomcat on node B is answering this request but can't display the application to the client. so every second request will end in a timeout...

is there any way to configure tomcat, to stop answering request until it has finished the startup procedure?

Comment: The easiest is to use a second subnet and routing, ea. route 10.10.10.2 to 10.10.20.2 and when 10.10.20.2 is down or booting route it to 10.10.20.1 which is node A, probably will take an extra lan card. If you run openresty or the Lua addon you can use Lua upstream and EBLB to dynamically manage your backends directly.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, when a node is restarting e.g. after some maintenance from the hosting-company i can't change the route on the proxy server because i'm not at work or something else.. i need something to disable the tomcat listening-port (8080) while it is starting, it has to open the port after finishing the startup and not while starting

Comment: Its not that hard to make a script doing the route changes and fire that from a protected php location so you can click on something, or have the script fire curl commands to see if the backend is running and change the route accordingly as an automated task. You can also do this with EBLB manually or via a curl script. Both will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need  to configure nginx health check appropriately. There are couple of extensions (e.g. https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module) that allow to specify `url` for  helth endpoint.

One possible  solution could be: 
Add health endpoint to all your apps, create and deploy a `health-management-app` that will ask  for  health (readiness) to all your apps and return status healthy as soon as get positive answer from all deployed apps.

It is just idea, but hope it will help you.

P.S. The idea is borrowed from  spring-boot-actuator frameworks. It has /management/health endpoint that in case of depends on other services (e.g. mongodb or elasticsearch) asks  all services for health and return  positive status only if all responses were positive.